# How to remove Bootstrap-container only from large screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want the container in both small and medium screens and its working fine. I want to remove the Container only from my large screen. I found nothing like container-lg-none. Please Help.
Any help is appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
<section>
    <div class="container m-organism-category">
        
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2 mx-lg-0 ">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid"alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2 m-atom-round-img">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
                <img src="http://assets.myntassets.com/dpr_1.5,q_60,w_400,c_limit,fl_progressive/assets/images/retaillabs/2021/1/28/85b47fa0-5e71-4f6d-bcf9-27946bd8d62f1611824554381-Kurta-Set.jpg" class="m-atom-round-img img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: remove ? , do you mean `display:none` ? if yes , then `d-lg-none` might be what you want .

Comment: Not remove, if i used d-lg-none, the contents will be hidden, i only want the "container class to not work"  in large screen.

Comment: okay, So what is that css rule of `.container`  you want to remove/reset  then ?  Is it : `width`, `max-width`, `padding`or `margin` ?

Comment: I tried removing the `margin` of the container class, but the contents(the images) aligns to the left and is not stretched across the screen(like the space between is shrinked(i used `justify content`: properties, but no use)).

Comment: did you use the class `m-0`or did something else? you have the `m-lg-0`class which does in the mediaquerie `min-width:992px` : `.m-lg-0{margin:0!important}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BS5 comes with a whole bunch of utility classes.

If you want container only for medium and small then replace:

```html
<div class="container m-organism-category">
```

with:

```html
<div class="container-md m-organism-category">
```

or, you can also use `container-float` for large and `container-md` for medium and small:

```html
<div class="container-float container-md m-organism-category">
```

If you want to get rid of the container altogether, then you'll need to reset the base class CSS.  Do so with the following CSS:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .un-container {
    max-width: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    margin: inherit;
  }
}
```

*(Drop that in a `<STYLE>` tag or in an add-on CSS file.)*

and then the html will be:

```html
<div class="un-container container-md m-organism-category">
```

*(If you're compiling from SCSS then use the `breakpoint-min` function in BS' `mixins/_breakpoints.scss`)*

Comment: But container-md affects larger screen too. I want the container class not to function in larger screen.

Comment: Yes... you're correct.  The base class sets `max-width`, left and right `margin` and left and right `padding`.  I've edited the answer to add a workaround.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This helps.:)